# C++ where are the flags for linking libraries documented?

Tags: c++, opengl, gcc, flags

With every new library I want to use I have noticed there is a specific flag, or set of flags, I have to add to the compile in order for it to actually link the library.

For example with GL GLEW and GLUT I use "`-lglut -lGLU -lGL`".

The problem is the only way to find these flags that I need is to search endlessly on google for them. Is there a 'standard' place to find these flags for any library? Are they appended to the tops of the headers or something? I hope it's just something obvious I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you are asking about GCC/G++ compiler.

The flag is `-l<libName>`, where `<libName>` is the name of the library you want to link against. For example, `-lGL` links against the GL library.

The reason some libraries require multiple flags in certain order is simply the way they depend on each other (the libraries your library depends on might also depend on some other ones, and so on). The library's documentation should solve the problem in most cases.

Comment: Yeah, GCC on Fedora 20. I forgot how different compilers and platforms can be with c++. Coming from a really heavy java/opengl background. Thanks for the tip though man.

Comment: And just to follow up. After a few trys I found the cURL library flag is -lcurl. Let's just hope the rest are this easy haha. Thanks again.

Comment: @newObjekt FYI, if you search the library install dir and find libXYZ.a or libXYZ.so, the commandline argument to add is libXYZ.  If there are version numbers involved, you might want -lXYZ-3 or something - but again it's just the filename without the leading 'lib' and file-type extension.

Answer (score 5):

Typically, you develop an intuition for discovering these things on the platforms you develop for.  It does suck.

For example, on my Debian development system, I would start by checking `pkg-config` for the library I want.

```
pkg-config --list-all | less -i
```

It looks like there's a package named `gl`.  So, you can get the linker flags using `pkg-config`:

```
pkg-config --libs gl
pkg-config --cflags gl
```

Then you can put that into your Makefile:

```
gl_cflags := $(shell pkg-config --cflags gl)
gl_libs := $(shell pkg-config --libs gl)

override CFLAGS += $(gl_cflags)
override LIBS += $(gl_libs)

my_app: my_app.o
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ (LIBS)
```

This doesn't work for all libraries, only those with `.pc` files installed.  For example, it won't work for LibJPEG.  In these cases, you would either remember the flags (`-ljpeg`) or you would use an Autoconf / CMake / etc. configuration script to discover the flags at configuration time.

And, none of this will work at all if you don't have the development versions of your libraries installed.

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

P.S. GLU is a bit obsolete.

Comment: I'm just getting the hang of working c++. I have a lot of experiance with OpenGL in java and I'll likely be purely using the GL11 GL20 and GL33 calls when I actually get used to this. I've also heard SDL is very good for this type of work in c++ so I may give that a go.